# ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified - Connecting to a remote database

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have two databases, CitadelStation and SQL_Course.

There is a table in the SQL_Course database called, `TEST` under the user, "course" whose password is, "course."

When I try to create a database link to this table from CitadelStation, I run into trouble. The command I used to create this database link is:

```
create database link remote_connection
connect to course identified by course
using 'SQL_Course';
```

The link is successfully created, but when I try to query the `TEST` table, I receive the following error:

```
select * from test@remote_connection;

select * from test@remote_connection
                   *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

What can I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Do you have an alias `SQL_Course` defined in your `tnsnames..ora` file (on the DB server for the DB you are creating the lonk in)?

Comment: Pay attention to what @Alex has said - TNSNAMES.ORA **on the DB server**, not your local file (on your own PC) (unless this is the database that is installed on your PC, such as 11gXE).